# How to solve this ODE: $(x^2-y^2+y)dx+x(2y-1)dy=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to rewrite it as
$$(x^2-y^2)dx+ydx-xdy+2xydy=0,$$
divide by $y^2$,then get
$$(\frac{x^2}{y^2}-1)dx+d(\frac{x}{y})+2\frac{x}{y}dy=0,$$

let $\frac{x}{y}=t, $and $\frac{dx}{dy}=t+yt'$,then
$$t^3+yt^2t'+t-yt'+t'=0,$$

But I don’t know how to calculate it later. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: $x^2-y^2$ or $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: Sorry, I re-edit my question.@aschepler

Comment: The way the ode is written, the book is most likely asking you to make it exact. Use an integration factor. There are well know standard methods to find integration factors to make an ode exact. That is not always possible, but I think the first step is to try an integration factor.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=y^2-y$,
$$(x^2-u)dx+xdu=0$$

Organize it, we get

$$\frac{du}{dx}-\frac1xu=-x$$

So we get a linear first order differential equation. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Thank you! But how did you come up with $u=y^2-y$? It's amazing. This equation looks like it was designed for this variable substitution.

Comment: Yes, if you inspect this ODE, it is "almost" exact, but just miss a $-$ sign, but we can solve it by making this sub instead. @Ychen

Answer (score 2):

Let $s=y^2-y.$ The equation rewrites
$$(x^2-s)dx+xds=0,$$
i.e. (dividing by $x^2$)
$$dx=-d\left(\frac sx\right)$$
The solutions are therefore
$$x+\frac{y^2-y}x=C,\quad C\in\Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 2):

$y^2-y$ and $2y-1$ suggest letting $y=u+1/2$, giving
$$
(x^2-y^2+y)dx+x(2y-1)dy=\left(x^2-u^2+{1\over4}\right)dx+2xudu=\left(x^2+{1\over4}\right)dx+2xudu-u^2dx = \left(x^2+{1\over4}\right)dx+x^2d\left(u^2\over x\right).
$$
This is easily integrated after dividing through by $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2-y^2+y)dx+x(2y-1)dy=0$$
$$x^2dx-(y^2-y)dx+xd(y^2-y)=0$$
$$dx+\dfrac {-(y^2-y)dx+xd(y^2-y)}{x^2}=0$$
$$dx+d\left(\dfrac {y^2-y}{x}\right)=0$$
$$d\left(x+\dfrac {y^2-y}{x}\right)=0$$
$$x+\dfrac {y^2-y}{x}=C$$